Encryption of PII data in database logic in store procedures and desktop application
I have an old desktop application (Delphi) with logic in stored procedures (Oracle). The application is storing some personal data including salaries. I want to encrypt data so someone with db access cannot check salaries of other workers. I face 2 problems:

desktop application: I cannot deliver encryption key with application because it can be easily revealed. I need to create some "proxy server" storing encryption key in middle of desktop application and sql server. This will make architecture more complex and will potentially create problems with performance.
Stored procedures: this will require a lot of changes but I this is doable with passing encryption key to store procedures from external system. Biggest problem here is that there are a lot of DB JOB and I don't see any solution for this.

In general, I think this would take huge amount of time and probably better solution would be to rewrite whole system.

You have asserted some things, but failed to ask an actual question. You've decided you need to rewrite the whole system, what do you need help with?

It seems that you accept situation that some unauthorized people may access your db. Why? Just don't let them. Problem solved.

@PhilipKendall The question is presumably "what should be done about the two problems listed."

@freakish: While I agree with the spirit of what you're saying, your words can also be taken to never need a second line of defense either - which is precisely the mistake made by people who e.g. store plaintext passwords. I think your wording needs more nuance to avoid the advice being understood in a harmful way.

@Flater I'm not sure where you see analogy between what I said and storing plain text passwords. It's the opposite: restricting access is more secure than encryption. Because encryption enforces you to setup key infrastructure, which is another point of failure.

@freakish "Plaintext passwords aren't a problem, we're restricting access to the database anyway!" The existence of database access restrictions is precisely what led people to not be concerned about storing plaintext passwords: they were fully relying on the DB security being foolproof. Again, I'm not saying OP has to encrypt their data, I'm merely cautioning your phrasing of your advice as it currently gives blanket permission to solely rely on a single line of defense for highly private information.

@Flater do you suggest that passwords should be stored encrypted? :) It's not really analogous, because hashing (not encryption) is a valid technique for passwords. And doesn't require encryption keys (with their infrastructure). Otherwise yes, it would be equally as hard.

@freakish: I'm not discussing what the best way to protect passwords is. I'm saying that blindly relying on only db access control isn't enough to protect highly sensitive data; as evidenced (for example) by prior incidents revolving data breaches that exposed credentials because the developers had stored these credentials in plaintext because of their blind reliance on db access control to keep everything safe and hidden.

@Flater well, the method matters. Because setting up encryption infrastructure for that only shifts the point of failure from db to the infrastructure. One may argue that it is better, but honestly, if someone hacks your application then he will hack the infrastructure as well. And so you've increased security only marginally by adding a lot of complexity. I don't believe it is worth it. Secondly, OP seems to be more concerned with privacy rather than security.

Such encryption would be useful if it was users who owned (and not share) their keys. But that forces a somewhat bad UX unfortunately, and most companies will avoid it. Even if it means less security. Sorry, that's reality.

The simple answer here is to restrict access to the data at the DB level in Oracle.  This assumes that you have a distinct oracle login for each user of the application which the application uses to access the DB.
It's not totally clear what your plan for encryption looks like but it does seem like a good solution would be complex and difficult to get working. If you were going to go down that path, a stored proc might not be a terrible way to go but you really end up with the same issue in the end: controlling access to the stored proc or keys.
UPDATE:
As Ewan notes in the comments, simply restricting access to the tables will not prevent someone with full admin rights to the DB from accessing the table. I don't think there's a way to completely eliminate anyone from ever having full admin access to the DB but there might be reasonable controls over that which can be put in place.
This kind of thing tends to be tricky, and a client-server architecture makes it more difficult, which is likely why you are talking about rewriting the whole system.  If you want to avoid that, one option would be to segregate this one aspect on the program into a more N-tier solution.  That is: set up a HTTP host which has access to the key(s) for encryting and decrpyting the data. The application then, would not directly retrieve the data from the DB or have acces to the keys, it would call a webservice which would determine the user's authorization and display the decrypted data they have access to see.
An astute reader may note that this amounts to moving the problem to a different server.  That is true and by itself doesn't address the root issues of how you restrict the access of privileged users (i.e., admins) to the data. What is does is give you much more flexibility while limiting the impact to the rest of the system.  Of course, if this is the main thing the system does, then maybe a full rewrite is the answer.

this doesn't seem to answer the question  "I want to encrypt data so someone with db access cannot check salaries of other workers"

@Ewan Huh?  Having access to the DB doesn't mean you have access to all tables in it. Oracle allows you grant access on a table-by-table basis (at the very least) I have access to a Oracle DB where I don't even have the rights to see that some tables exist, much less access them.

sure but presumably there is a DBA somewhere who needs full access for maintenance, but isn't allowed to see salaries

You need to do both, granular access rights, and encrypted data at rest.

@Ewan If that is the requirement, then yes, access controls won't be good enough. Access auditing might be an option. It's not clear who needs access to the data exactly, though, beyond (presumably) HR staff.

@Ewan a problem that no company ever experienced. Just let the DBA see what he needs to see. Btw, the only way to prevent that is if users own (and don't share) their encryption keys, which seems is not what OP wants.

its a standard legal requirement in the UK to encrypt CC details on the db.

tbh im kinda surprised with the pushback on this, OK mainly we get away with just ticking the "full db encryption" option, but for specifics like CPI and PPI anonymisation/separate encryption etc is pretty standard

@Ewan which article precisely mandates such encryption in UK? A lot more than just full db encryption? Because it sounds unlikely. Also anonymisation is a completely different thing.

@freakish Can you clarify what you mean by 'full db encryption'? I assume that you mean disk encryption which doesn't address this concern. If you mean something else, I'm definitely curious about it.

@JimmyJames yeah, lets say disk encryption. Databases also typically give ability to do additional, built-in encryption of their files. Which exactly law mandates that this is not enough? I'm quite sure there is no such law in EU, but hey, maybe something changed in UK since brexit.

@freakish Disk encryption has no effect on what someone can see when they query the DB in the same way HTTPS doesn't prevent users from seeing the content of webpages.

@JimmyJames and where did I say it does? More importantly: that's not what I'm asking about.

@freakish That's the whole context of this question. I'm not sure why you would expect us to assume you are talking about an unrelated issue.

@freakish A quick search yields "PCI DSS Requirement 3" as the regulation around protecting CC data in the UK.

@JimmyJames have you read the conversion? Maybe you should one more time

@JimmyJames PCI DSS not only it is not required, but even if it was, it doesn't mandate any granular row level encryption. Simply false.

@freakish I think you should consider following your own advice given you jumped into a conversation between myself and Ewan on my answer.

@JimmyJames apologies, I didn't know you own conversations at SE.

@freakish I don't but you don't seem to be following and it's unreasonable to expect us to change what we are discussing because of that.

@JimmyJames do I force or expect you to do anything? It is you who put words in my mouth, and ignore what I say. Your problem is not my problem, dude. Seriously. You don't want to talk, then don't.

@freakish I don't really know anything about those regs but this page discusses that and says "When data is stored, it should be stored securely. ... Encryption, truncation, masking and hashing are critical components of cardholder data protection." Disk level encrpytion doesn't seem adequate based on that.

@freakish You realize that I am notified every time you add a comment to my answer, right?

@JimmyJames and that is a reason I'm not allowed to talk? Fascinating. Keep going.

@freakish You are fine to keep commenting.  I don't mind but it's very strange to keep addressing me and acting like it's none of my business.

@JimmyJames I've never once addressed you before you addressed me. Not everything is about you, dude. Why am I even continuing this pointless conversation? Actually, I'm done. I have better things to do.

@freakish And if you comment on my answer, don't be surprised if I challenge something you write. This answer and the conversation was about how to protect data from users with access to the database (not the file system or physical disk.) Disk encryption has no relevance to that (something you don't dispute.) It's pretty simple.

@freakish Thanks. I appreciate your going away.

@JimmyJames you challenge something I didn't say, not even suggested. And then you bark for bizarre reasons, like I'm not allowed to talk with other people on your thread because you get notifications. XD And finally, you challenge again the same claim I've never said, and now explicitly denied. XD Sure, something to be proud about. This time I'm out for good. Good luck! You're gonna need it. XD

@freakish UK PCI regulations specify particular encryption is used for storing parts of the CC information, and also that other parts are not stored at all. Full disk/db encryption doesnt meet these standards. GDPR has less specific but similar rules around PPI information. Full disk encryption does box tick a whole bunch of regulations, but isn't enough in of itself for these extra secure bits because, as jimmy points out its effectively bypassed on any db login, so doesn't meet the goal of preventing the sysadmin and other no authorised users reading everyone's card details.

it's an interesting question about whether banks themselves have to adhere to PCI, as they effectively police it.

@Ewan that's incorrect. I can clearly read on the PCI DSS site "The PCI DSS is a standard not a law, and is enforced through contracts between merchants". Secondly, you claim that full db encryption doesn't meet these standards, yet, I can't see a single line on their site that indicates that. In fact there are broad statements there like "Encryption, truncation, masking and hashing are critical components of cardholder data protection" which doesn't mean anything. Furthermore the site mentions criminal hackers multiple times, it is about unauthorized access, not authorized.

In fact I can read this: "Cryptographic keys should therefore be stored securely and access restricted to the fewest custodians necessary." which clearly indicates that it allows people like DBAs to access sensitive data. Sorry, but the claim you've made is just false. Or at least misleading.

And no, GDPR does not mandate any encryption at all. It hardly even mentions encryption. It only talks about duties to make system secure and obligations and penalties in case of data breach. But it doesn't mandate concrete solutions.

@freakish im not sure which but you think is wrong, they are "regulations" yes, but if you want to process credit cards you have to follow them and the standard approach is just to encrypt the fields they want encrypted before you put them on the db. The sysadmin doesnt need to see the CC deets, so they dont get the key. simples.

no GDPR is much more vague, they don't want to get tied down, whereas I think the banks got stung by early DES encryption not being strong enough. However, if you want to pass a GDPR audit you will have to show how you carefully secure PPI information and don't let the sysadmin (not necessary) read everyones stuff

@Ewan well, I don't know much about UK, so I'm not going to argue about that anymore. Especially since it seems that in order to read the actual PCI DSS v4.0 document you need give them your personal data. What an irony. XD As for GDPR compliance I can assure you that EU banks allow some sysadmins to access all the data, and it doesn't affect audit at all.

I can well imagine it having experienced firms with multi year PCI wavers. But it seems like a clear breach to me. We will likely only know if they get sued. The point is though that implementing off database encryption is standard and easy

@Ewan Another thing someone might take away is that insisting that given requirements aren't real and insisting that you know better is a great way to alienate people such as customers.

@JimmyJames i did book a BnB over the phone once and I could hear the owner writing down my card details. She didn't care about no dam regulations, prob has a waste paper basket full of CC fraud opportunities her cleaner needs full access too

"The secretary is responsible for keeping my files, but I don't want her to be able to read the files". That's the essence of the problem here.
The word "secretary" is related to the word "secret", and means an officer who is entrusted with the private information of the principal (either a person or an organisation).
The modern sysadmin is effectively the remainder of the senior ranks of what used to be the clerical, secretarial, or record-keeping staff of an organisation.
It's a surprisingly common scenario today that management finds it necessary to entrust supervision of its data processing machinery to someone who they don't actually trust to handle that data - as if the need for trustworthiness in such a role was an afterthought.
If you're dealing with an old application that was written with certain assumptions in mind regarding the security architecture, you may really have little other option but to continue obeying that architecture - which means granting direct access to the database only to trusted staff, in accordance with the assumption around which the original application was designed.
However, standard database engines like Oracle have significant facilities for restricting access to data, so I'd be surprised if it wasn't possible to create a specific login and clamp down on what it can access. It's not clear why you haven't considered this option, before considering fancy encryption schemes.
Nevertheless, there are often ways around the limitations if staff have sufficient physical access to the computer or overall permissions within the server environment, and if they have determination to access the data rather than just idle curiosity. The need to select an appropriate person for the most senior supervisory roles is never completely avoided.

its normal to encrypt private data to prevent theft style attacks. ie I hack into Sony's PlayStation users database because i guess the admin pass, I download everything, but everyone's emails and personal data fields are encrypted and the key is not in the database, so I cant read them

@Ewan, but private to whom, and who decides to whom the organisation's data is private? Most standard encryption schemes are designed to defend the sysadmins from various kinds of subversion of their authority, not to prevent sysadmins themselves from viewing data or making decisions about access.

private as in the end users "personal private information", (in this case the salary), whom as in everyone who doesn't require access in order to provide the services purchased/agreed to by the customer (in this case HR or the accounts dept). Sure salary is a bit of an edge case, employees aren't customers. imagine credit card numbers instead

@Ewan, I've worked in a few banks and I can assure you there was nothing stopping the very lowest clerk, hired a week ago, from rifling your personal info including your credit card numbers. For very good reason, of course, that the clerks had various legitimate reasons to access the data when solving problems. The issue at hand is who has the practical power to decide who sees what, and what requirements justify access. In general regarding data belonging to the organisation, the sysadmins have that practical power.

"To comply with PCI DSS requirements, companies must use strong encryption algorithms like Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) or Triple Data Encryption Standard (3DES) to protect sensitive information during storage, transmission and processing. Additionally, they must have secure key management practices in place and use only approved cryptographic modules"

@Ewan, protect the data from whom? From thieves and eavesdroppers, or from the sysadmins themselves? The point I'm trying to make is that by default there are always staff (at least 1) in an organisation who have the power to see the organisation's data without restriction, and to decide who else is and isn't prevented from seeing it by various measures. In a retailer that takes payments, there are staff who can decide (as a practical matter) whether to apply or disapply encryption schemes - regardless of whether they are breaching regulations or breaking the law in doing so.

in this case the PCI regulations protects the data against both hackers and dbas.

to use your secretary analogy it's like giving them a locked cabinet to keep the files in. Sure they still have the key and can get files out, but the overnight room maintenance person cant

@Ewan, but we aren't dealing with the "overnight room maintenance". We're dealing with somebody who is actually a sysadmin - who has the key to the room, the key to the cabinet, who has legitimate access to the cabinet which also contains the salaries, and whose explicit function is to oversee (to at least some degree) the clerical activity which involves that cabinet and the comings-and-goings of files to and from that cabinet. It's risible to equate that to the office cleaner or the site caretaker, whose jobs are not clerical in nature.

@Ewan, (...2/2) your understanding of the situation does exemplify what I'm saying is the problem though: the perception that senior roles involving the oversight of the organisation's confidential data, is somehow equivalent to being the night cleaner!  You can treat your company secretary like the night cleaner, of course, but it doesn't change the amount of control he actually has over confidential data.

the night cleaner, maintains the room, but has no legitimate reason to look at the files. like the dba maintains the database but has no legitimate reason to see the CC numbers

@Ewan, my argument is not that the sysadmin has a legitimate reason to see the salaries either. My argument is that it is virtually impossible to stop staff from viewing data, when they are tightly involved in the organisation and mechanics of storing and processing that very same data. And my point is that this is not a new problem, since it can be traced in the etymology of the word "secretary", but many do not see the connections.

my argument is that the sysadmin is not the secretary, they are a cleaner, and its trivial and normal to encrypt specific data in the db so that they can't see it.

@Ewan, so who in your organisation applies that encryption, and who controls who else in the organisation is allowed to decrypt the data again?

Generally regulations require that more than one person be involved in the process and that you audit the events to prove you are following the rules. So in this case you might implement a system where the secretary has to sign out the key, noting which file they are going to retrieve in a log and the lock has some counter for how many times its used. The purpose is to make it so no one person can bypass the system. Now obviously several bad actors could team up, bribe the auditor and steal the files.

Which is exactly the argument against Chinese companies data protection, whatever measure they put in place, ultimately the government can choose to override them by ordering all those people to cooperate. A

and FOR end to end encryption, which reduces the reliance on the company and governments

But your argument that the sysadmin has god mode access and nothing can be hidden from them is just wrong.

@Ewan, I'm not necessarily saying things cannot be hidden from any particular person, especially if the concealment scheme can be elaborate and the overheads and constraints borne. What I'm saying is that, in practical computer systems, there invariably is a "god" - a superviser, a person (or a set of people) with the factual power to control the machinery on behalf of the organisation. That often includes deciding how rules and regulations are complied with, whether rules and regulations are even complied with at all, and how the machinery works in the first place. (1/2)

You can indeed devise complicated schemes with distributed authority and control, requiring multiple people to act to achieve anything, but in practice these systems are difficult and expensive to develop, and they come with strange constraints like if one sysadmin is suddenly off sick, then the other cannot work (because he has no sole power to do the necessary things). So sysadmins often end up with sole powers. (2/2)

these "complications" and "difficulties" have been standardised away. if you process CCs you have already implemented a process you can use for salaries, or anything else. If you comply with GDPR you already have audit processes in place dealing with this exact problem

@Ewan, my current employer (like previous employers) protects salaries by just storing them separately from the bulk of organisational data - in ways that are overseen by different people than me, not in ways where those overseers themselves have no access to the data.

I don't think encryption is appropriate here.  Redaction is probably a better bet.  Then whoever is logged into the system will either see the data or not.  If it was an SSN or some other PII then encryption is a better choice because the data should be protected at all times (in transit/at rest).
Here's an example:
https://blogs.oracle.com/cloudsecurity/post/columnlevel-security-oracle-databases-data-redaction
In the summary section of the article, it indicates what level licensing is needed for data redaction feature if using on-prem.
One could also write some code that could check which user is logged in and then redact or mask the data appropriately.  For example:
if (user != admin || user.role != manager) {
 salary = mask(salary);
}

It would take too much effort to do that for certain fields, even if the application is ancient.

"desktop application: I cannot deliver encryption key with application because it can be easily revealed"
Public Key Cryptography
Give the public key to the desktop and keep the private key for your admin application, or store it in an OS protected keystore  with user control access.
So for example, if we assume your application is deployed to a secretaries PC, it must be able to read and write the secret data, it runs locally and the DB is on prem in another room:
Your flow for adding an employee might be

HR user logs in
Clicks "add employee"
Fills in the form with name and secret salary details
clicks "save"
app requests public key from keystore
OS checks logged in users permissions and returns key
app encrypts secret details
app uploads encrypted data to DB

User try's to read data would be

Disgruntled Worker logs in
clicks "search employee details"
app requests data from DB
DB returns encrypted data
app shows blanked fields
User edits memory to get UI to show the data
app requests private key from OS
OS checks users permissions
OS says No
app throws error

User steals PC

Disgruntled Worker steals PC and takes it home
hacks motherboard TPM, windows security etc and gains admin access
copies private key
adds to their users keystore
repairs pc
can't get salary data because it's on the database.

User steals database

Disgruntled Worker steals database server and takes it to home lab
can't decrypt because key is in another castle

Database Admin gets curious

DBA logs directly into database
select * from employees where id='boss'
gets encrypted data
decryption key is not kept on the database.

So to gain access, I have to steal the key and also the database which are both in a secure office.
Admittedly if you are putting the key on every laptop in the company and people take them home. it's maybe not the best idea. But from the description it sounds like the OP has a pretty basic setup.
Also, this doesn't solve the "SProc needs to perform salary calculations" problem. But this is literally a contradiction in terms. You can't have someone with access to the database not be able to see the data but also be able to see the data.
If that is not secure enough, then you can use my first suggestion. A different app for decryption. that way you can keep the private key on a single special PC in a locked room. The downside is your normal app cant view the data at all.

OS protected keystores are usually not considered secure enough for PII.

you got a reference for that?

It just seems like you rely on the os access management for a whole tonne of stuff which wouldn't be allowed if it was true.

for example, jimmy james' answer effectively does the same thing on the DB. if you log in with admin, it decrypts the data for you

I don't see how using a public key for decryption prevents access.

you use the public key for encryption. I have expanded with examples

@Ewan I'm not the downvoter, and i don't see anything encryption related in Jimmy answer. The reason OS key stores are not considered secure is because they are unlocked upon user login, this tying their security to the security of the user password. You have to further secure your private key with another password, but then the problem is where you store that password.

@Ewan A client-side key pair could be an option but the user who owns the data needs the private key. The windows keystore can do a pretty good job of protecting the private key as long as it set up right.  But anyone with admin access to the desktop can extract it, or at least that was the situation last time I checked.

@Ccm i think the OS will protect the key from users without access.

@JimmyJames yes an admin will be able to read the key, that is true

@Ewan From what I recall, even with admin access to the OS, it wasn't simple to extract a private key (that is set to be unexportable) but someone with enough technical skill could work it out.  That might have changed in the years since, but I doubt there's a way to make it impossible for someone with admin rights and access to the physical device.

@JimmyJames its not a solution I would goto first that's for sure, but given the OPs lack of hosted API layer. If you are just stuck with a delphi desktop app and an office DB, its a simple way to avoid having a plaintext key in the config

@Ewan Agreed. There are more robust versions of that approach using specialized hardware or secret managers but it's unclear what resources the OP has to work with.
